# How can I move all files in subdirectories recursively to a single directory?

Tags: command-line, find

I am trying to collect all the files under the current directory and all the subdirectories to one directory. I am trying something like the following

```
find -type f -exec mv {} collection/{} \;
```

the above command won't work because the second `{}` gives the full path, how can I collect all the files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the `{}` from `mv`, `mv` will take it as target directory ignoring any parent directories:

```
find -type f -exec mv {} collection/ \;
```

Comment: As I say in my answer to the question, this is potentially a bad idea. Maybe using the argument `-maxdepth 1` would help.

Comment: Come to think of it, it seems like I read your question wrong :) Sorry.

Comment: @loevborg: I've added "recursively" to the title now. If there is still confusion, please edit it and improve it :)

Comment: a faster variation of this answer is `find -type f -print0|xargs -0r mv -it colection/`

Comment: Could you explain the components of the command? Also, how will this handle duplicate files?

Comment: @PeterCullen For every file path `path/to/file`, the command `mv path/to/file collection/` will be executed given the `find -type f -exec mv {} collection \;` command. If you end up with duplicates such as `path1/to/file` and `path2/to/file`, the second match will overwrite the earlier `collection/file` entry. To avoid silently overwriting files, you can add the `-i` option to `mv` and it will interactively prompt you whether to overwrite a file or not.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `find` (which does the job well), you could also use the shell to this end.

Say you want to all files from $PWD to $DEST. The natural attempt would be:

```
mv $PWD/* $DEST
```

How does this work? The expression "$PWD/*" expands to the names of all files in that directory. This shell feature is called "globbing". The last argument of `mv` is the destination directory. If you have very many files, this won't work because the length of the command line is limited.

But the solution has the problem that it omits dot files - or "hidden" files, files and directories whose name start with a ".". To solve this, you have to tell your shell to include dotfiles when globbing. To do this, use

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

when using `bash` (and you probably use `bash` unless you've changed the default). In this shell, the above command will work for dotfiles as well.

As an aside, in `zsh`, you have the option to choose this on a case-by-case basis. To do this, put

```
setopt extendedglob
```

in your `.zshrc`. Then you can use

```
mv $PWD/*(D) $DEST
```

to move all the files, including dotfiles. (The "D" has the effect of temporarily enabling the "GLOB_DOTS" option).

Now the original question was to move all regular files (not directories) from all subdirectories and their subdirectories to a single directory. This can be accomplished with `zsh`:

```
mv $PWD/**/*(D.)
```

Here the expression `**/*` makes the globber descend recursively into subdirectories. The `D` means "also select dotfiles'; the `.` means "only select regular files, not directories".

Comment: well i wanted to recurse into all the sub-directories too,but thanks any way the information is useful , come across this situation too a lot of times :)

Comment: Actually, find is not overkill for this, globbing will select all matches, not just files, but also directories. If you're worries about performance, you could also use something like: `find -type f -exec mv -t collection/ {} +`. Consult the manual page on how this works.

Comment: Lekensteyn, you're right. I updated the answer now that I've understood the question.

Comment: Wonderful answer, too bad that it's not particularly relevant to the question :).